# Visual studio 2012 is terminating/restarting during running the windows phone 8 app

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator, event-viewer

I am working on a windows phone 8 app, few days ago it was running properly but since last day Visual Studio 2012 Professional is not working properly it is restarting during executing the wp8 app. I put the breakpoints to debug into my app but in actual cursor is not even intitalize the app.xaml.cs.

So for detection the error i searched the Windows.Log from the event viewer there i found errors logs. But i am unable to understand that juggle. I am writing that event log as code please give me some helpful suggestions.

```
two error logs were there.

**first one is '.Net.Error'
------------------------**
    Log Name:      Application
    Source:        .NET Runtime
    Date:          1/2/2014 7:04:52 PM
    Event ID:      1026
    Task Category: None
    Level:         Error
    Keywords:      Classic
    User:          N/A
    Computer:      Ashish-PC
    Description:
    Application: devenv.exe
    Framework Version: v4.0.30319
    Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
    Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
    Stack: at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
    at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[])
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
    at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
    at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

     Event Xml:
     <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
      <System>
       <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
       <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID>
       <Level>2</Level>
       <Task>0</Task>
       <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
       <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-01-02T13:34:52.000000000Z" />
       <EventRecordID>562583</EventRecordID>
       <Channel>Application</Channel>
       <Computer>Ashish-PC</Computer>
      <Security />
     </System>
     <EventData>
       <Data>
          Application: devenv.exe
          Framework Version: v4.0.30319
          Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
          Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
      Stack:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[])
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

=================
Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          1/2/2014 7:04:52 PM
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Ashish-PC
Description:
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Stack:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[])
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-01-02T13:34:52.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>562583</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Ashish-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Stack:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[])
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

**Second one is 'Application.Error'
--------------------------------**

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          1/2/2014 7:04:52 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Ashish-PC
Description:
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.61030.0, time stamp: 0x5270a974
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16408, time stamp: 0x523d4548
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00012eec
Faulting process id: 0x1cf4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf07bf2f983579
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: a87d9549-73b2-11e3-befa-844bf5a2c13e
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-01-02T13:34:52.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>562584</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Ashish-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>11.0.61030.0</Data>
    <Data>5270a974</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.3.9600.16408</Data>
    <Data>523d4548</Data>
    <Data>e0434352</Data>
    <Data>00012eec</Data>
    <Data>1cf4</Data>
    <Data>01cf07bf2f983579</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>a87d9549-73b2-11e3-befa-844bf5a2c13e</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

===================

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          1/2/2014 7:04:52 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Ashish-PC
Description:
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.61030.0, time stamp: 0x5270a974
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16408, time stamp: 0x523d4548
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00012eec
Faulting process id: 0x1cf4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf07bf2f983579
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: a87d9549-73b2-11e3-befa-844bf5a2c13e
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-01-02T13:34:52.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>562584</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Ashish-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>11.0.61030.0</Data>
    <Data>5270a974</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.3.9600.16408</Data>
    <Data>523d4548</Data>
    <Data>e0434352</Data>
    <Data>00012eec</Data>
    <Data>1cf4</Data>
    <Data>01cf07bf2f983579</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>a87d9549-73b2-11e3-befa-844bf5a2c13e</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my above issue, actually i had installed some extensions in Visual Studio 2012 which were free from the Microsoft like power tools extensions and such type authorized plugins through extensions and manager, i uninstalled those plugins and restarted my PC. Visual Studio 2012 started working properly as i purchased it.

Thank God! :)

Comment: RedGate Reflector extension was the issue for me. Go to Tools-> Extensions and Updates -> Select Red Gate Reflector Extension and restar VS